# troubleshooting - Turn on a single led in a ws2811 ledstrip with an arduino Uno with FastLed

Tags: arduino-uno, led, c, electronics

I want to to turn on a single led in a ledstrip running on `ws2811` with an Arduino Uno.

The problem is that when I try to turn just one of them on, they all three light up. The strip is a 3-wire strip, with `GND`, 12V and `DIN`. I am just running an example from the Arduino library `FastLed`

My code can be seen below

```
// Use if you want to force the software SPI subsystem to be used for some     reason (generally, you don't)
// #define FASTLED_FORCE_SOFTWARE_SPI
// Use if you want to force non-accelerated pin access (hint: you really don't, it breaks lots of things)
// #define FASTLED_FORCE_SOFTWARE_SPI
// #define FASTLED_FORCE_SOFTWARE_PINS
#include "FastLED.h"

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Move a white dot along the strip of leds.  This program simply shows how to configure the leds,
// and then how to turn a single pixel white and then off, moving down the line of pixels.
// 

// How many leds are in the strip?
#define NUM_LEDS 3

// Data pin that led data will be written out over
#define DATA_PIN 6

// Clock pin only needed for SPI based chipsets when not using hardware SPI
//#define CLOCK_PIN 8

// This is an array of leds.  One item for each led in your strip.
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup() {
    // sanity check delay - allows reprogramming if accidently blowing power w/leds
delay(2000);
FastLED.addLeds<WS2811, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);

}

// your leds.
void loop() {
  leds[0] = CRGB::Red;
  leds[1] = CRGB::Black;
  leds[2] = CRGB::Black;
  FastLED.show();

}
```

Comment: There appears to be [several versions of this chip](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2811.pdf).  Does your chip have pin 7 (SET) populated?  Also, are you building this from scratch?  (If so please post the schematic.) Is there a resistor between 12V and the VDD of the chip?

Comment: That is just the way those led strips are wired. They are sets of 3 leds connected to a single WS2811 chip. Those chips only have 3 color channels.